# No code actions available when trying to implement a specific interface

Tags: typescript

Im facing an issue when trying to implement an interface thats automatically generated (therefore i cannot change the definition of the interfaces or its types to solve the problem).

It seems like, code actions are not available when trying to implement an interface that defines a function with a return type `DeepPartial<T>` (definition below) where T is a type with two attributes having the same interface as a type i.e. `{a: Nested, b: Nested}` where `Nested` is an interface

I wrote the following to further pinpoint the problem:

```
// taken from ts-proto generated files

type Builtin =
  | Date
  | Function
  | Uint8Array
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | undefined;

export type DeepPartial<T> = T extends Builtin
  ? T
  : T extends Array<infer U>
  ? Array<DeepPartial<U>>
  : T extends ReadonlyArray<infer U>
  ? ReadonlyArray<DeepPartial<U>>
  : T extends {}
  ? { [K in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[K]> }
  : Partial<T>;


// testing code action for implementing interfaces

interface Nested {
  field: string;
}

interface Foo {
  request(): DeepPartial<{ nested1: Nested; test2: Nested }>;
}

interface Bar {
  request(): DeepPartial<{ nested: Nested }>;
}


// no code action available
export class FooImpl implements Foo {}
// code action available
export class BarImpl implements Bar {}
```

Furthermore, after adding the code to [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and trying out different versions of TypeScript I noticed that this problem only occurs for TypeScript version > 4.3.5

I am wondering if there are any tsconfig options that could be refined in order to resolve this problem or if this is a potential bug that has been introduced after v4.3.5 and should be reported as I see now actual issues with the implementation of the DeepPartial type or the interfaces I provided.

Thanks in advance for any assistance:)